# Why my router is not lazy importing component ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

I using `react-router-dom` but its not importing my component lazily. I dont know what is wrong. I dont have any error or warning. Its just not showing my component.
For make it more clear my sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-thunder-kz7sy?file=/src/App.js

If you dont have time for check sandbox my codes :

**AppViews**

```
export const AppViews = () => {
  

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading..</p>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/dashboard`}
          component={lazy(() => import(`./dashboard`))}
        />

        <Route
          exact
          path={`${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/commons`}
          component={lazy(() => import(`./commons`))} 
        />

        <Redirect
          exact
          from={`${APP_PREFIX_PATH}`}
          to={`${APP_PREFIX_PATH}/commons`}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default AppViews;
```

**Commons**

```
const Commons = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading cover="content" />}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path={`${match.url}/documents`}
            component={lazy(() => import(`./documents`))}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>

      <Redirect from={`${match.url}`} to={`${match.url}/documents`} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default Commons;
```

After that my url is turning `localhost:3000/v1/commons/documents` but my `Documents` component doesn't import. My screen shows nothing. What is wrong in that codes ? I tried to delete `exacts` and tried again but still same. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Go take a look at this:  https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/lazy-loading?file=src%2FApp.tsx